# Why am I getting "Cannot resolve symbol"?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I've imported this project before, with no difficulty before.  I'm not sure what has changed.

I click `Import Project` and selected `getting-started-with-selenium` (http://github.com/ddavison/getting-started-with-selenium) which is a Maven project, and an old Eclipse project.  I clicked the directory, then in the "Select libraries" or whatever, i selected `Maven`.

I've changed my build path to match correctly...

```
src/
  main/
    java/  <-- source folder.

  tests/
    java/  <-- tests folder.
```

But yet, I get `"Cannot resolve symbol 'After'"` Even though in the maven libraries, I see it clearly.
[image]

Let me know if there is any additional information needed.

Comment: Can we see your POM?  My first guess would be that you have junit scoped to `test`, but accidentally put `AutomationTest` in `src/main`.

Comment: That was it Mark... I had `<scope>tests</scope>`  Go ahead and mark that as an answer.

Comment: [This](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/configuring-testing-libraries.html) solved the problem for me. See also [this.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4757951/183704)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Make sure that if JUnit is declared as `<scope>test</scope>`, that your test class is in `src/test`, otherwise it won't be able to see the dependency.

Comment: unrelated, but if you're familiar with intellij (i just recently tried it for myself) could you maybe offer some insight on why I even had to add the junit dependency?  If you look at http://github.com/ddavison/getting-started-with-selenium/tree/master/pom.xml you can see that i don't even HAVE junit as a dep.  But Intellij had no problem before.. my guess is that i didn't import the project correctly.. maybe i should import the `.project` for eclipse projects next time, then manually add maven support?

Comment: @sircapsalot: Since IntelliJ has built-in support for JUnit, it might have automatically added JUnit as a non-Maven module dependency, ignoring your pom.xml.  For example, I have a Maven project without JUnit in the pom.xml.  I create a new JUnit4 test through IntelliJ.  `@Test` flags an error, so I use Alt-Enter.  The first autofix suggestion is to "add junit.jar to the classpath" (not through Maven).  A later autofix suggestion is to "Add Maven dependency", which would actually change the pom.xml.  If you choose the former, the test class won't compile when building through Maven.

Comment: @Mark Peters
   mostly the Alt+Enter is solved my issues regardins "can not resolve..."
 But i atleast minimized the number of errors with the ALT+Enter

Answer (score 5):

Make sure that you can compile the project through Maven (that is, via command line) through `mvn clean compile`.

If that generates errors, be sure that you have the junit dependency properly scoped in the POM.

If that doesn't generate errors, then it's IntelliJ that doesn't know where the new libraries are.

To fix that, simply go to the Maven Projects tab in the main window, and hit the "Generate Sources and Update Folders for All Projects" button.  Then, hit "Reimport All Maven Projects", which is next to the previous button.

Answer (score -1):

I have a project in Eclipse.

1. Click right mouse button on your project root -> Context menu
2. Select this menu : Maven > Update project