# IntelliJ cannot resolve Junit for Maven project

Tags: intellij-idea

The closest post I could find on SO is: [Why am I getting "Cannot resolve symbol"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21339934/why-am-i-getting-cannot-resolve-symbol)

But it didn't help me. :(

Here's my error screenshot:
[image: commercial photography locations]

And I've made sure that my pom.xml is scoped to  and my actual code is also put under test folder.
Here's my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.fishercoder</groupId>
    <artifactId>leetcode-algorithms</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Also

```
mvn clean compile
```

runs success.

Here's the result of

```
mvn test
```

Here:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running com.stevesun.AddBinaryTest
Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.042 sec
Running com.stevesun.MissingRangesTest
Tests run: 6, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 sec

Results :

Tests run: 10, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.913 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-01-08T09:13:22-08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 16M/308M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I'm guessing it's something funky with my IntelliJ setup?

Comment: everything looks right to me. So if this doesn't work. Just close the project and open a pom.xml from intelliJ. It will offer to "recreate" idea files - do it and intellij should re-parse the whole pom.xml into native intelliJ project again. this should help

Comment: I just did as you said, no luck either. Thanks Mark.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

EDIT - Solved via Comments: 
In your screenshot, there is a `test.iml` located in your test folder. Is there perhaps an exclusion or something? Can you try deleting that file?

---

You can try to Invalidate Caches in IntelliJ (via `File | Invalidate Cache`).

You can also try and rebuild your project from within the IDE (via `Build | Rebuild Project`).

You could also try to *Synchronize the Project* (Reimport All Maven Projects) via Maven (there should be a Maven Tab somewhere on the right side or via typing *Maven Projects* into `Ctrl + Shift + A`).

Comment: Thanks Marc. I've tried all three methods you mentioned, still no luck.

Comment: In your screenshot, there is a `test.iml` located in your test folder. Is there perhaps an exclusion or something? Can you try deleting that file?

Comment: OMG, that did help! Thanks a lot @Marc

Comment: Glad it helped you :)

Comment: (IJ 19.3.4) To get the maven support I had to right click the pom and select add maven.

Comment: File | Invalidate Cache worked in my newly created maven project.