# Problems when importing AssertJ and JUnit

Tags: java, junit, import, assertj

I'm at university and I have to submit a project. I'm having problems with Assertj and JUnit when importing. I'll leave below some images of my problem.

[image]

I'll really appreciate if someone could help me! Thank you!

Comment: Did you include the dependencies in your pom file or added the jars to the class path?

Comment: I really don't know how to do that, it's my first time using this libraries. Could you explain me how to do it?

Comment: are you using any IDE like eclipse ?

Comment: Just google it: "How to add jar to class path in " + your IDE (fe Eclipse).

Comment: kswaughs --> I'm using Intellij IDEA IDE.

Comment: for you reference [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757800/configuring-intellij-idea-for-unit-testing-with-junit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757800/configuring-intellij-idea-for-unit-testing-with-junit)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why but sometimes not including scope will make it work.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
    <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.22.0</version>
    <!--<scope>test</scope> --> <!-- I have commented this line out and it worked -->
</dependency>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to get both the junit and assertj jar files added to your class path. You can either do this within your IDE manually (Intellij includes the junit library, but you'll have to download assertj seperately and add them as dependencies as outlined [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/configuring-testing-libraries.html)), or by using a build system that downloads dependencies from a central repository, like [maven](http://maven.apache.org). You can then [get intellij to use your `pom.xml`](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/maven.html) (maven build configuration), so everything can still be run from within your IDE.

A trivial pom might be something like the following:

```xml
<project>
  <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-project</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
      <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
      <!-- use 3.1.0 for Java 8 projects -->
      <version>2.1.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```