# Intellij does not run tests

Tags: java, intellij-idea

After importing my project into Intellij and getting it to build successfully, I am trying to run some of my project's tests. I navigate to the test file and select Run -> Run. However, this does not run my tests, just opens a small "Edit Configurations" window, as the attached photo shows.

[image]

And, when I select Edit Configurations as prompted, JUnit is not to be found. The window is shown below.

[image]

What do I need to do to run the tests?

Comment: Are your tests actually inside of a Test Source folder?

Comment: Please review [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757800/configuring-intellij-idea-for-unit-testing-with-junit).  I'm guessing your IntelliJ cannot find the JUnit JAR, and this is why it is not appearing in the drop down (it appears in mine).

Comment: Check in Project settings -> Modules that you test package is marked as Tests.

Comment: Right click on the test class name either in the code window or in the project panel, and select Run <classname>. If you don't see the run menu in the popup then you haven't selected a test or you don't have junit plugin installed.

Answer (score 2):

For me it was also an issue with my pom.xml. After checking [Junit5-samples pom](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5-samples/blob/r5.6.2/junit5-jupiter-starter-maven/pom.xml). I noticed the test plugin was missing. So I only needed to add:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.2</version>
</plugin>
```

You may also want to check if your pom contains:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
    <version>5.6.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

For me this was an issue with my `pom.xml` and using `JUnit5` with `IntelliJ` because my tests were not getting detected and it said `0 executed 0 skipped` etc.

Here's what I added to my `pom.xml` to get `JUnit5` tests to run in `IntelliJ`:

```
    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.21.0</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2.0-M1</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
                    <version>5.2.0</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

And here's the dependencies I added:

```
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.easytesting</groupId>
        <artifactId>fest-assert-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0M10</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0-M1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.0-M1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to click on your project and click on **Run 'All Tests'** . After that, go to 'Edit Configurations..' and make sure you are using `-ea` value on VM Options area.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

makre sure you IDEA have installed the Junit plugins and Junit jar in your classpath:[image]

and then just click this place to run test case:

[image]