# Intellij IDE Not Running Unit Tests

Tags: intellij-idea

I am running IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.1 and am attempting test a class with the integrated test runner. The test seems to compile but not run.

This is a multi-module Maven project, and other modules have tests that run. However, I have not been able to find any differences between the projects. The surefire plugin is specifically defined on this project, and `<skipTests>` is specifically set to false. I have reimported the project several times in case the maven configuration is affecting the built-in runner.

The image below is the only output I get. Debug/Breakpoints will not stop.

[image]

If anyone can help or throw possibilities at me, I would appreciate it.

**Edit:**

Here's a simplified version of the test I'm attempting to run:

```
package com.jason;

// imports

@RunWith(BlockJUnit4TestRunner.class)
public class MyTest {

    private ClassUnderTest clazz;

    private DaoClass dao;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
       // using Mockito to mock the DaoClass

       // injecting the DAO into the ClassUnderTest
    }

    @Test
    public void testMethod() {

        Assert.assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

I attempt to run the test by right-clicking on the method annotated with `@Test` and clicking run. The option to run the test DOES appear in the context menu. When I do so, all that appears is the screenshot.

I have attempted to do the following to troubleshoot the issue:

- - In the `pom.xml` file for the appropriate module, I have manually specified the surefire plugin in the `<build><plugins>` section. I then did a reimport to pick up the changes.
- I have put breakpoints in the code and run the test in debug mode.
- I have attempted to log output, both with an slf4j logger and a System.out.println()
- I have attempted to find any differences in the IDEA .iml file between a module where the tests run and this module where the tests do not run.
- I have written a very simple test class, with a method annotated with `@Test` and containing the line `Assert.assertTrue(true)`

**Edit 2**
 Attempting to run mvn test -Dcontrollername produces the following output:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) on project rma-svc: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test failed: The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
```

**Edit 3**

I've updated my Maven surefire plugin to 2.22.2 and am not seeing the forked JVM issue any longer. However, running `mvn test -DskipTests=false` outputs `No tests were executed!`

Comment: Have you tried to ensure the code is actually being ran by including some kind of logging in your test methods?

Comment: Yes, I have, both with a regular logger and a System.out.println()

Comment: And I am assuming you've actually tried running the test in debug mode and tried to assert simple conditions that you knew were gonna fail the test?

Comment: Yes, did that too. It never displays the output pane, as described as #4 on this link: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/test-runner-tab.html

Comment: Would be great if you could include everything you've tried so far in the question so we don't have to chat in the comments like this.

Comment: See edited post

Comment: Have you tried running `mvn test` manually?

Comment: You said you tried to make it fail. Try to flip you assertion to false and see if the test fails.

Comment: I'm unable to run maven from the command line due to a separate issue.

Comment: Attempting to run `Assert.assertFalse(true)` did not produce any test output.

Comment: Perhaps see if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51852779/5759072

Comment: I've updated again with the output of `mvn test` from the command line. I don't know if this affects the IntelliJ issue or not.

Comment: @Jason Does that mean your issue was resolved then?

Comment: No, the issue is not resolved. I cannot run the tests in IntelliJ or via the command line. For ease of use, I would rather use the IntelliJ runner.

Comment: I had the same with intellij, it is due to an old version of the sure fire plugin if you are running locally java 11

Comment: I've updated my surefire plugin to 2.22.2, which is the most recent. I'm also only using a Java 8 JDK.

Comment: Please tell if the issue is reproduced with IDEA 2019.1.3? Can it be reproduced with little sample project? If yes, please share.

Comment: @OlgaKlisho: I have asked this question in the community forum as well.  https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360003952660-TestRunner-Doesn-t-Run-JUnit-Tests . I am starting to think this is a carryover from the original import of the maven project into the IDEA project. I will check if the problem occurs in 2018.3.6, but I have to ask my IT people if my license covers 2019.