# how can I add junit.jar in intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea, junit, jar

when I write `import org.junit.*` the IDE says can not resolve symbol junit and show it in red color. then I can't even import unit test; 
niether junit nor groovy Junit.

and I thought maybe I should first install the junit.jar, but junit already has been installed in plugins!
how can I install junit.jar? if it's necessary

it's not how to add jUnit to my program but how to add that plugin (maybe)
that question is here [configuring intellij ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757800/configuring-intellij-idea-for-unit-testing-with-junit)

the IDE is intellij community edition and my OS is linux.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Configuring IntelliJ IDEA for unit testing with JUnit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757800/configuring-intellij-idea-for-unit-testing-with-junit)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have installed JUnit plugin for IntelliJ IDEA, that means that IDE recognizes and support JUnit tests.

However, you are missing JUnit dependency on your classpath. That mean add proper JAR file to the classpath or if you are using dependency management tool such as maven, add it to your dependencies section.

---

**Alternative 1 - Maven dependency - put this in you pom.xml file under** `<dependencies>`

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.12</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

---

**Alternative 2 - Gradle dependency - put this in your build.gradle file**

```
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

---

**Alternative 3 - Download the JARs and put it on your classpath.**

Download the following JARs and put them on your classpath:

[junit.jar](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg:%22junit%22%20AND%20a:%22junit%22)

[hamcrest-core.jar](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg:%22org.hamcrest%22%20AND%20a:%22hamcrest-core%22)

Comment: I have JUnit installed IntelliJ but somehow junit is red for me... except its not a Maven or Gradle project so no pom.xml. Any ideas? On Windows I was able to just Create a test right off the bat!

Comment: You can add library manually under File->Project Structure->Libraries

Comment: I do this, more often now. It works properly, I suppose!

Answer (score 5):

From the main menu, select  *File->Project Structure-> Libraries*

and click <kbd>+</kbd> and select from maven

after when open the dialog prompt

type `org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.4.2` in the dialog prompt

ex-:

[image]

now, click <kbd>ok</kbd> and run again

Answer (score 1):

It's also worth double checking your configuration to make sure your test run config is pointing at the test portion of your project, not the entire project.

Comment: Thanks, that was it for me.