# Which way I should use to do unit test in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: java, unit-testing, intellij-idea, junit

I had read [Configuring IntelliJ IDEA for unit testing with JUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757800/configuring-intellij-idea-for-unit-testing-with-junit), but it can't solve my problem.Here is my problem.

I use IntelliJ IDEA for Spring Boot Project,now I want to do some unit tests.So firstly I add junit dependency in my pom file.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

And next step, I install the JunitGenerator V2.0 plugin.
And then,it seems that there are two ways that I can choose to generate test file.One of them is using Alt + Insert in class file and choosing Junit Test to generate test file.And the other is using Ctrl + Shift + T or Alt + Enter to generate test file.

My problem is, what's different between them?And which way I should choose?

Comment: How is that a problem? Just generate two files and see if there's a difference.

Comment: Oh I forget to speak, firstly I can use  Alt + Insert to generate test file.But after I do some configuration in IDEA Setting-Junit Generator,It can't work.I use  Alt + Insert again,this time nothing changed.@Tom

Comment: so you made a mistake in the configuration of the plugin... By default it doesn't put generated test classes in the correct location (src/test/java)