# java.lang.Exception: No runnable methods

Tags: java, junit

I'm doing some JUnit 4 test for my project. I have already read stackOverflow solutions but none of them has helped. 
During running single JUnit test I got an error

```
java.lang.Exception: No runnable methods
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.validateInstanceMethods(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.collectInitializationErrors(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.validate(ParentRunner.java:416)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.<init>(ParentRunner.java:84)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:65)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:111)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
```

I tried to Invalidate Caches, have junit-4.12.jar and hamcrest-core-1.3.jar in my library root. Still got errors. 
Here is my code

```
    import org.junit.Before;
    import org.junit.Test;

    import static org.junit.Assert.*;

    /**
     * Created by Asus on 2018-01-06.
     */
    public class ZamowieniaRepositoryTest {

        ZamowieniaRepository zamRepo;

        @Before
        public void setUp() throws Exception {
            zamRepo = new ZamowieniaRepository();
            Zamowienie zamowienie = new Zamowienie();
            zamRepo.zamowienie = zamowienie;
        }

        @Test
        public void utworzPozycjeZamowienia() throws Exception {
            Towar towar = new Towar(2,"Wkladki",870);
            PozycjaZamowienia pozycja = new PozycjaZamowienia(0,towar);
            assertEquals(0,zamRepo.utworzPozycjeZamowienia(towar).getId());
            assertEquals(pozycja.getTowar(),zamRepo.utworzPozycjeZamowienia(towar).getTowar());
        }

        @Test
        public void sprawdzDostepnoscTowaru() throws Exception {
            zamRepo.zamowienie.dodajPozycje(new PozycjaZamowienia(0,new Towar(0,"Srubki",30),25,5));
            zamRepo.zamowienie.dodajPozycje(new PozycjaZamowienia(1,new Towar(0,"Wkrety",85),47,2));
            assertEquals(true,zamRepo.sprawdzDostepnoscTowaru(0,25));
            assertEquals(false,zamRepo.sprawdzDostepnoscTowaru(0,38));
        }

        @Test
        public void usunPozycje() throws Exception {
            zamRepo.zamowienie.dodajPozycje(new PozycjaZamowienia(0,new Towar(0,"Srubki",30),25,5));
            zamRepo.zamowienie.dodajPozycje(new PozycjaZamowienia(1,new Towar(0,"Wkrety",85),47,2));
            zamRepo.zamowienie.usunPozycje(1);
            assertEquals(1,zamRepo.zamowienie.getSize());
        }

}
```

Sorry for not english code. 
Thanks for any help! ;)

Comment: Are you using Maven or Gradle as a build tool? If so, can you update your answer and show the dependencies you are importing? I fear that you have a problem with the project setup.

Comment: I'm not sure where to check my dependencies. Could you please tell me where they are?

Comment: @Martyna: your code looks correct to me in terms of the JUnit usage. So the problem must be a setup problem. I assume there are no compilation problems, correct?

Comment: No compilation problems. Actually in Event Log it says that Compilation completed and then Test Failed.

Comment: @Martyna I suspect by the screenshot that you  are using IntelliJ IDEA. Is this correct?

Comment: @Martyna Check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757800/configuring-intellij-idea-for-unit-testing-with-junit . Does this help?

Comment: Don't write your code in other language than English, ever.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you double check your imports. For debugging purposes name your methods with a pattern like `testMyFlow()`. You might be having imported or using as a runner an older version of JUnit for some reason.

You can also try annotating your class with:

```
@RunWith(JUnit4.class)
```

This will always invoke the JUnit's 4 default runner. More info [here](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/test-runners).

Also, if you want to use `Mockito` you need to annotate the class with a test runner:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ZamowieniaRepositoryTest {
```

Comment: The imports are actually ok. I believe that the project is not setup properly.

Comment: I know that the copied code looks ok in terms of imports, but who knows what he actually has

Comment: I extended my class with TestCase and used pattern. Tests passed. Why is that? What could I do to work it with the @Test annotation way?

Comment: You have an older version of JUnit imported, probably by your IDE. To do this correctly, you should user Maven or Gradle. They will import the dependencies correctly for you, without worrying that you have something else imported. What IDE do you use?

Comment: I'm using IntelliJ

Comment: Right click on the project -> Open Module Settings -> Modules -> Check Dependencies tab or Libraries. You might find a JUnit there that is an older version than 4.12 that you specified.

Comment: So there I have: JUnit4 as scope Test and junit-4.12.jar as scope Compile

Comment: Check my updated answer. Maybe it helps. Btw, `TestCase` is from JUnit 3.x.x and so is the pattern with `testXXX()`. The annotation `@Test` was introduced in JUnit 4.

Comment: Yes, the difference I understand. I checked update with @RunWith(JUnit4.class) and it doesn't help. I really don't understand why since i have JUnit4 in my dependencies.